# Viewport above scroll to header stretches under header when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a webpage that starts with the navigation at the bottom and then scrolls to top. The issue is that when the nav fixes at the top and I resize the screen vertically the top div stretches down under the header.

I have tried to implement different z-indexes, so that it can hide under the index div, and I have tried to add a js function that removes the visibility and I have tried this:

height: calc(100% - 65px);

Here is a fiddle to show my problem: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Vee24/L7x4u0qc/

Any ideas on how I can fix this?`

```
<div id="screen"></div>
<nav>
</nav>

<div id="mainwrap">
<div id="index">
        <h2>home</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint blanditiis perspiciatis nesciunt possimus minus molestiae culpa necessitatibus atque ut eveniet id magnam delectus reprehenderit! Ad atque aperiam rerum quas vitae!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit esse nihil iusto ea natus aliquam enim ducimus deleniti vitae quibusdam</p>
</div>
</div>`

body { 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
background: pink;
}

#screen {   
background: #43b29d;
height: 100vh;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}

nav {   
width: 100%; 
height: 50px; 
bottom: 0; 
padding: 0;
position: absolute; 
overflow:hidden;
background: blue;
z-index:10;
}
.fixed {
position: fixed; 
top: 0; 
height: 50px; 
z-index: 10;
}

#index { 
height: 500px; 
width: 100%; 
margin-top: 220px;
position: absolute;  
z-index: 5;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
   var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 50;
         if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
             $('nav').addClass('fixed').css("z-index", "9999");
         }
         else {
             $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
         }
    });
 });
```

Comment: I am not able to understand the issue properly. The nav's initial position is bottom. and when you scroll up, the navabar scrolls till the top of the page.  Correct ?.. Now if you vertically increase the height of the fiddle from top,  the navbbar is still fixed at top and hence the green area starts showing.. Obviously it will..  Now what exactly do you want should happen to the navbar or the top div when you try to resize the screen vertically ??  I might be able to help you if you explain what is exactly that you need.

Comment: I need to hide the green area from stretching below the header once the header is fixed at the top, it causes a visual problem as it overlaps the background of the index div. I really hope you can help, I've been battling with this for days.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I can rezise the screen horizontal and vertical without the problem that the green area is moving blow the nav

Comment: @Vee: The green area does not stretch. It just comes into view when you vertically increase height of screen from top and its just that the nav is at top so it comes behind it. Do you want to stretch the pink area and resize the green area so that it does not show ?? Instead of thinking in terms of code. Just think about what should happen logically in the case you want. I can definitely help, but you need to first understand and think about what is needed.  Do you have an example which you can show me where i can see what you want. That would be helpful ...

Comment: Here are links to my images: http://postimg.org/image/nyeb6j3lz/     http://postimg.org/image/slm0xcd1v/   The first image is how it is coming it to view and the second one is how I want it to look. @mechanicals you are correct I want to resize the green area so that it does not show. The only time it should come in to view is when the header is not fixed at the top, I hope this is making sense?

Comment: @mechanicals Solved it! Thanks for replying though, just changed the jquery to: 
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var navHeight = $( window ).height() - 250;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > navHeight) {
     $('nav').addClass('fixed').css("z-index", "9999");
     $(".screen1").css("visibility", "hidden");;
    }
    else {
     $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
     $(".screen1").css("visibility", "visible");
    }

Comment: @Vee: Congratulations :) .